# Images cannot be shown in html

Tags: python, html, django

Images cannot be shown in html.I wrote codes in models.py

```
class POST(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

in views.py

```
def top(request):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    return render(request, 'top.html',{'content':content})
```

in top.html

```
<div>
         {% for item in content %}
            <div>
                 <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
                 <img src="{{ item.image }}"/>
            </div>
         {% endfor %}
</div>
```

When I access in browser, html is shown.`<h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>` is shown but `<img src="{{ item.image }}"/>` is not there.When I see page source in GoogleChrome,`<img src="/images/photo.jpg"/>` is shown. But when I click the url,404 error happens.My application has image/images folder, in images folder surely my uploaded picture is in there.I really cannot understand why this happens.I wrote MEDIA_ROOT&MEDIA_URL in settings.py so I think image is shown in browser. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your /images folder is visitable in Django. an easy way to get it done is to add the "images" folder in settings.py. like:

```
IMAGE_URL = '/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images"),
    '/images/',
]
```

Then in your html file add {% load images %} on the top.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have these lines in your project urls file

```
# Your imports ....
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [.......]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And in your template use

`{{ item.image.url }}`

Answer (score -1):

Use relative folder:

```
<img src=".{{ item.image }}"/>
```

resulting in

```
<img src="./images/photo.jpg"/>
```

and check if the upload worked and the image is there.

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote codes `<img src="./image/{{ content.image }}"/>` & `<img src="./{{ content.image }}"/>` but image is not shown there.How should I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:  `<img src="/image{{ item.image }}"/>`

**/** : means "**Root**"

**.** : means "**Current directory**"

so if your root application has image folder you need to start your path with /image

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur codes & `<img src="../image/{{ content.image }}"/>`,but image is not shown.I added ` {% load staticfiles %}` in front of html but same situation happens.I added in settings.py `IMAGE_URL = '/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images"),
    '/images/',
]`

Comment: html file is in templates folder

Comment: if your server is Linux (I think it is), check your permission for your images and image folders too, with chmod command (in Linux). finally, you will get the image if when you see your source code from the browser and then copy and paste the URL of the image and if you can't see it, it means permission for that folder isn't enough or your addressing is wrong

Comment: please check when you write the URL on the browser, does it show your image or not? can you show your image with a specific URL? if yes please write the true full address here.

Comment: and please tell me when you used `<img src="/image{{ item.image }}"/>` what was the results in your html code ? thank you